# How to record audio with Azure Kinect DK?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azurekinect

I got an Azure Kinect DK unit today and I am trying to save recordings for the analysis. I need both audio and video for the analysis. I am able to save the recordings but there is no voice in the recordings. 
Surprisingly, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/azure-kinect-recorder) of the Kinect also mentions that it cannot record audio. I wonder if this has a microphone array then how come it does not store audio! Is there any other way to store/log the audio with the video steam?

Comment: So, what how did you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The microphone for Azure Kinect DK can be accessed through the [Azure Speech Devices SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-devices-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can try pyaudio(https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/). You can find the corresponding microphone device using get_device_count() and get_device_info_by_index(). Number of channels can also be specified.

It works with my Kinect DK. I changed the number of input channels to 7 since DK has an array of 7 microphones. The result is a nd-array with dimension (X,7), where X is the length of your audio. I am not certain whether each channel corresponds to a unique microphone, but there are variations among the 7 columns of recordings.